# Set mouse debounce time

Tags: xubuntu, mouse

When I right click my mouse "receives" the command 2-6 times. Example: on Terminal, when I right click (to Paste something), it will immediately open (at least) another Terminal (because the mouse is in the same position as the Open Terminal option).
I could fix this on Windows by having an AutoHotkey script which set a delay of about 50ms between clicks.

I've tried checking Mouse and Accessbility options but the few options available only work for left click. In another forum someone suggested me to check **evdev** but its manual did not help me alot; searching for it, I found about **xkbset**, which I think can do the trick, but again, its [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/xkbset.1.html) is not meant for beginners.

*It is indeed a cheap USB mouse with faulty hardware, but one should be able to fix this particular problem, as someone with accessbility problems could need this*

Thanks,

Comment: solutions are mentioned at this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/321816/mouse-sometimes-doubleclicks-when-i-click-once

Answer (score 1):

Ahhhh this is interesting.  I am strictly hardware and not into Ubuntu (except for however it may intersect with KiCad.)  I use an old Logitech trackball.  My main (select) click is a right click. It recently began double clicking when only a single was intended.   Adjusting double click speed in Windows 10 did not help.  About a week ago I built a simple debounce circuit and connected it inside my trackball.  Seems to fix the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I posted in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451864/116842), this should be fixed with libinput 1.9.

[Announce](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/wayland-devel/2017-October/035469.html):

> Pointer devices now have button debouncing automagically enabled.
>   Ghost button release/press events due to worn out or bad-quality switches
>   are transparently discarded and the device should just work.