# Disable mouse wheel doubleclick

Tags: mouse, input-devices, mouse-wheel

My mouse's wheel sometimes doubleclicks instead of single click. Looks like hardware issue.

How can I prevent sending another wheel click for one second for example?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/321816/mouse-sometimes-doubleclicks-when-i-click-once for more solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's hardware issue, I suggest you to slow your double-click function.

You have to go to **System Settings** --> **Mouse & Touchpad** --> **Double Click** (adjust it to "**Slow**")

Comment: "Fast" settings made doubleclicks occur much more seldom, so I accept your answer while currently no 100% solution was proposed. Thank you :)