# How to disable double click for the left mouse button and enable it on another button instead

Tags: mouse, doubleclick

I've read way too many pages on the issue over the past two or so years but nothing seems to work for me up to now.

Is it possible to disable doubleclick altogether instead of changing doubleclick speed as here https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/mouse-doubleclick.html.en ?

My mouse multiple clicks when I single click about 80% of the time, which makes it really difficult to use. I've tried various mice and they all do the same. So the assertions here (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MouseCustomizations) and here (https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/mouse-doubleclick.html.en) that the mouse must be faulty do not seem to apply in my case. Both mice listed below in the "xinput --list" output present the same problem.

I've already lost some documents as a result of extra clicks causing documents to be overwritten due to incorrect options being accepted by extra unwanted clicks.

What I would like now is to disable doubleclick for the left mouse button altogether and enable it on another button instead, e.g. to doubleclick when I press down the middle button. Could someone guide me on how to achieve this? Many thanks.

ps. I've already tried options such as this [mouse sometimes doubleclicks when i click once](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321816/mouse-sometimes-doubleclicks-when-i-click-once) and https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=316441

---

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

---
$ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SIGMACH1P USB Keyboard                    id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse USB Optical Mouse       id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HID compliant-mouse HID compliant-mouse   id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SIGMACH1P USB Keyboard                    id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Trust Webcam                              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is now solved. I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 and this seems to have eliminated the problem. Both my mice work fine now and so I have no more need of tinkering with the buttons to avoid unintended double-clicks.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Comment: Do you happen to know what changed? I'm running Kubutu 20.04 and I don't think I'll get an update any time soon that would fix it for me as it did for you.

Answer (score 0):

Open Gnome Settings, follow this path: '/devices/Mouse & Touchpad' and select the button you wish to be your primary. Is that what you're looking for?
The above is the path for 18.04, I assume 16.10 will be similar.

Comment: Hi Dithers, thanks for your comment. No, this is not what I'm looking for. Double-click is tied to the primary button (which I have already set to the slowest possible). I wish to de-link double click from the primary button so that it becomes impossible to double-click when I intend to single-click.